# underscore js pluck nested key value

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a JS object like this one

```
var obj = {
    "2014" : {
        "11" : {
            "20" : {
                "Counts" : {
                    "c" : 2
                }
            },
            "21" : {
                "Counts" : {
                    "c" : 20
                }
            },
            "22" : {
                "Counts" : {
                    "c" : 20
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "_id" : "53d6883a2dc307560d000004",
    "createdate" :"2014-11-21T07:15:26.109Z"
};
```

As you can see this is structure which contains year>->month->day->counts->c->value structure
I want to pluck out the day and Count(c) values out of it

I tried something like this

```
_.pluck(obj,'11')
```

but this is good uptil only month, and doesn't work for days like

```
_pluck(_.pluck(obj,'11'),'20')
```

Comment: I don't get it. You want to summarize all of the "c" values for month==="11" ?

Comment: My exact need is to get all the values of "c" in a given daterange like  finding all the C's in 21 and 22 dates

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use map like this. Pluck is a refined version of map.

```
_.map(obj.2014.11, function (item) {
  return item.Counts.c
}
```

This will give you an array with all c values embedded in 11.
But I would not be suprised if I have misunderstood your intent...

Comment: which is pretty much i wanted, can we pair the "date" along with the value, that is the item key name itself

Comment: done _.map(obj["2014"]["11"], function (item,key) { return key + " " + item.Counts.c;});

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would have created the data structure keyed by date, and then created views (this looks a lot like a couch structure) based on them:

```
var obj = {
"2014-11-20" : {
   "Counts" : {
      "c" : 2
   }
},
"2014-11-21" : {
   "Counts" : {
      "c" : 20
   }
},
"2014-11-22" : {
   "Counts" : {
      "c" : 20
   }
},
"_id" : "53d6883a2dc307560d000004",
"createdate" :"2014-11-21T07:15:26.109Z"
};
```

But given your existing structure, you may just need to do a reduce (actually multiple):

```
var allcounts = _.reduce(obj,function(result,item,key) {
  // key is now "2014", item is the value of {"11":....}
  _.reduce(item,function(result,item,key) {
    // key is now "11", item is the value of {"20":....}
    _.reduce(item,function(result,item,key) {
      // key is now the date, like "20", item is the value of {"Counts":{"c":2}}
      result.push(item.Counts.c);
    },result);
  },result);
},[]);
```

Ugly, but I cannot think of a better way with this kind of deeply nested data structure

You can limit the range by working with the `key` var in the first, second, third `_.reduce()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
var obj = {
                "2014" : {
                    "11" : {
                        "20" : {
                            "Counts" : {
                                "c" : 2
                            }
                        },
                        "21" : {
                            "Counts" : {
                                "c" : 20
                            }
                        },
                        "22" : {
                            "Counts" : {
                                "c" : 20
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                "_id" : "53d6883a2dc307560d000004",
                "createdate" :"2014-11-21T07:15:26.109Z"
            };


     for(x in obj){
        // console.log(obj[x]);
         for(y in obj[x]){
             for(z in obj[x][y]){
         console.log(obj[x][y][z]);// your output here
             }
         }
     }
```

but it will be good to construct date wise if possible for your implementation.